# imageview in android resolution

Tags: android, imageview, geometry

i would like to know how to view the image in a circle view ?! like the imageview in instagram or like the other applications that can be put  an imageview . In fact i would like to control by display the image in a circle or square .

Comment: did u tried any thing ?

Comment: oh thats awesome ! thanx body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the below code

```
 public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
    bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

final int color = 0xff424242;
final Paint paint = new Paint();
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
final float roundPx = 12;

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setColor(color);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

return output;
```

}

Comment: could you tell me where I put this code exactly ? I mean I want to open an image from my phone and choose it , after that I want a specific size of the imageview and if its not I crop it and after that it shows it in a circle view. Hopefully didn't its not too much :)

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18378873/957654)
and please five me some feedback

Hope that Helps .